# http request missing through httpInterceptor angular 8

Tags: angular8, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to add a static Authorization header for our internal portal but some file downloads are missing from getting header added

below is the code I am using

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {       
   intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

   request = request.clone({
     setHeaders: {
     Authorization: `Basic rpzLuipWBVhKgGIyuiicxA$qbegGnPytnn$IZYzn3GrugiKeQMRIm4LsCwVqb0Qs`        
   }
});
   return next.handle(request);
}
}
```

Comment: have you added the TokenInterceptor as "provider" in your module component?

Comment: yes added. Not all http requests are missing from interceptors. Only anchor tagged file downloads are missing.

Comment: <a href="/api/download?file" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Download to Excel file</a>

Comment: you are saying that the header used in the intercept works well (authorization), but some of them doesn't work, its right?

Comment: yes. those some which are not working are getting called through anchor tags - example - <a href="/api/download?file" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Download to Excel file</a>

Comment: basically they are not XHR requests.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `httpInterceptor` works only for `xhr` requests. Since Anchor tags doesn't come under that category, below is the work around done.

```
openPdf(fileLink, fileName) {
    // Prevent default behavior when clicking a link
    // $event.preventDefault();
    // Get filename from href
    //var filename = fileLink;
    this.http.get(fileLink, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).subscribe(function (data) {
      const file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      const element = document.createElement('a');

      element.setAttribute('href', fileURL);
      element.setAttribute('download', fileName);
      element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(element);
      element.click();
      document.body.removeChild(element)
    });   }
```